# Show or hide Elementor sections with Jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, elementor

https://staging-regattaatnewriver.kinsta.cloud/floorplans/

Hello im trying to show/hide section on the page above using jquery.

```
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery('#colorselector').change(function(){
      jQuery('.colors').hide();
      jQuery('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

and this select field

```
<Select id="colorselector">
 <option value="red">One</option>
 <option value="yellow">Two</option>
 <option value="blue">Three</option>
</Select>
```

i have all the matching IDS and CLASSES on elementor[image: classes and ids]
but when i select something all the fields dissappear and nothing shows. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I see in your site, you have two selectors with id="yellow, red, blue", and id most be unique, so that may this issue
Another issue: (index):98 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function when you click on change

Comment: @AneesHikmatAbuHmiad i removed the extra selectors , looking at my code how do i fix that?

Comment: I put answer and explan how you can fix it

Comment: @AneesHikmatAbuHmiad yes A+! do you know how to add a option that would should all ?

Comment: Thank you, you can do that by adding a new option with value null or all, and check if this value come, then you can jQuery('.colors').show(); nested of hide, and this will be work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one of these issue:

1. Your ID is not unique in website, and its most be unique
2. You have an error in select on your demo (`index):98 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` and need to make sure you are include jQuery or allow to $ (for fix this just replace `$(this).val()` to `jQuery(this).val())`)

Work example:

```js
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery('#colorselector').change(function(){
      jQuery('.colors').hide();
      jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Select id="colorselector">
 <option value="red">One</option>
 <option value="yellow">Two</option>
 <option value="blue">Three</option>
</Select>

<!-- Simulate your issue -->
<div id="red" class="colors">Red 1</div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors">yellow 1</div>
<div id="blue" class="colors">blue 1</div>


<div id="red" class="colors">Red 2</div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors">yellow 2</div>
<div id="blue" class="colors">blue 2</div>
```

Comment: @Annees thank you! that worked, i switchted the $ for jQuery and it worked....now i need to figure out how to make a selection that will show all